# Video Filters for Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I know this is a broad question but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for and it may be because I'm not searching for the right terms. What I am looking for is for someone to point me in the right direction.

Out of curiosity and to learn something new I would like to create a video filter for Microsoft Teams. This is way outside of my day to day kind of work.

The goal is just to create a rudimentary video filter. Like the "hello world" for Microsoft Teams video filtering.

Your help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Teams Does not support video filtering. This is by design.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that Teams per se supports filters, but something like OBS could suit your needs. OBS supports virtual cameras and can then become the video input stream for Teams, and I'm pretty sure OBS supports video filters.

Comment: Thanks Hilton. I'll take a look when I have the opportunity. I've moved on since posting this topic.